# How to store recurring calendar events in Firestore to allow complex queries

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, nosql

I want to be able to store calendar events in Firebase Cloud Firestore, each of them as a separate document. I am struggling to define the data model that would allow storing recurrent (or not) events and query them easily from Firestore.

Events, when recurrent, shall have a start date and an optional end date. An event shall be able to be configured with different recurrence rules similar to what is defined by [RFC5545](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5545#section-3.3.10): events could have different types of frequencies (none, weekly, monthly, ...), defined by a calendar parameter (week number, weekday, month day, ...), ... And would also allow for excluding specific dates.

The question is if there is a standard model for No-SQL databases that would allow to perform queries on easily retrieved events. For example, query all the events that take place on Fridays, or events that take place on a specific date 2024-01-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is if there is a standard model for No-SQL databases that would allow to perform queries on easily retrieved events.

No, there is not. In the NoSQL world, we are usually structuring a database according to the queries that we want to perform. So if you already know the queries, then structuring the database schema won't be difficult.

> For example, query all the events that take place on Fridays, or events that take place on a specific date 2024-01

Yes, that is perfectly achievable as long as you have inside the document fields that hold such data. For example, if a document holds the day of the event, and if the value of that is set to "Friday", then you can perform a query that looks like this:

```
val queryByDay = db.collection("events").whereEqualTo("day", "Friday")
```

Comment: Hey there. Did my answer help? Can I help you with other information?

Comment: Absolutely, @alex-mamo! While I was initially exploring a standardized solution, your response has provided valuable insights into crafting a custom implementation that suits my needs.